# What do Composer's "Your requirements could not be resolved" messages tell me?

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to use `composer require` to install some `drupal` modules from within a docker container that I'm using for my development environment, and I'm getting an error message that I don't understand. I've looked online for the documentation but most of the sources out there seem to be about how to resolve dependency issues, but I'm more interested in understanding the error message itself so I can't solve this problem in the generic case.

```
------
 > [18/19] RUN composer require -n     drupal/devel:4.0.1     drupal/console:1.9.4:
#22 0.260 Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
#22 19.18 ./composer.json has been updated
#22 19.24 Loading composer repositories with package information
#22 20.31 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
#22 37.86 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
#22 37.86
#22 37.86   Problem 1
#22 37.86     - drupal/console 1.9.4 requires drupal/console-core 1.9.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.9.4].
#22 37.86     - Installation request for drupal/console 1.9.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/console[1.9.4].
#22 37.86     - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v4.4.9
#22 37.86     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.4.9
#22 37.86     - drupal/console-core 1.9.4 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ~2.8|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.0-BETA1, v3.2.0-RC1, v3.2.0-RC2, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.0-BETA1, v3.3.0-RC1, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.0-BETA1, v3.4.0-BETA2, v3.4.0-BETA3, v3.4.0-BETA4, v3.4.0-RC1, v3.4.0-RC2, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 2.8.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.15 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.16 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.17 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.18 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.19 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.20 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.21 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.22 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.23 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.24 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.25 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.26 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.27 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.28 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.29 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.30 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.31 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.32 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.33 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.34 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.35 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.36 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.37 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.38 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.39 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.40 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.41 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.42 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.43 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.44 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.45 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.46 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.47 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.48 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.49 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.50 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.52 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v2.8.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 3.0.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.0.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 3.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                              #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 3.2.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 3.3.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher 3.4.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.1.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.15 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.16 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.17 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.18 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.3.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-BETA3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-BETA4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.1 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.10 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.11 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.12 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.13 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.14 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.15 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.16 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.17 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.18 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.19 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.2 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.20 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.21 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.22 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.23 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.24 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.25 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.26 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.27 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.28 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.29 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.3 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.30 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.31 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.32 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.33 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.34 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.36 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.37 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.38 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.39 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.4 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                 #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.40 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.41 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].                                                                                                                                                                                                #22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.42 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.43 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.44 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.45 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.5 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.6 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.7 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.8 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.9 conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86     - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.4.9) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.9].
#22 37.86
#22 38.40
#22 38.40 Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
------
```

Here's my understanding so far;

> #22 37.86     - drupal/console 1.9.4 requires drupal/console-core 1.9.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/console-core[1.9.4].
> #22 37.86     - Installation request for drupal/console 1.9.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/console[1.9.4].

I told composer to install `drupal/console:1.9.4` and it has found an exact version match.

> #22 37.86     - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v4.4.9
> #22 37.86     - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.4.9

I'm not sure, but I think maybe composer thinks that `drupal/console` is the same as `symfony/console` and therefore it has to remove `symfony/console:4.4.9` before installing `drupal/console:1.9.4`?

Then there are many lines of `symfony/event-dispatcher vx.x.x conflicts with symfony/console[vx.x.x].` which I really don't understand the meaning of.

> - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v4.4.9) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.4.9].

I think this one is just telling me that the only way to meet the `symfony/console:4.4.9` requirement is by installing that exact version, which it has previously decided (for some reason) not to install.

What I don't understand is where the conflict is. Is it because `symfony/console` and `drupal/console` are incompatible? Why?

Comment: `drupal/console` is nearly one year old and should be replaced by a more recent version. Can you share more details, for example about why you run `composer require` in something that looks like a build of a Docker image? Why not use a static `composer.json`?

Comment: Additionally, just have a look at https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/console-core#1.9.4 - the list of package versions contains a obvious requirement for `symfony/console` in versions `~2.8|~3.0`

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know enough about composer to answer your first question. Regarding the 2nd one - that's not really what I'm asking for here, I want to understand the error message.

Comment: Which part of that error message are unclear? You try to install a package that is not compatible with the rest of the packages you've already installed

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know how to rephrase it. I'd like to know from the error message which requirements are conflicting (not just _that_ there is a conflict), so that next time I see a message like this I'll understand what I need to change.

Comment: @NicoHaase regarding your first comment, I really don't know what a static `compose.json` does or why I'd use it instead of `composer require`. I'll have to do some reading on that one...

Comment: Can you share more details about all this? How are you using `composer require` after all? To me, the error log looks like some container building, and that's definitely not how you should use `composer require`. Use this during development, and only use `composer install` during building your containers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal/console-core 1.9.4 requires symfony/event-dispatcher ~2.8|~3.0`
and every one of the satisfiable versions of symfony/event-dispatcher `conflicts with symfony/console[v4.4.9]`

Change your version constraints for symfony/console or remove it first otherwise, you can not install drupal/console 1.9.4.

If you must have symfony/console v4.4.9 then you need to find a different version of drupal/console. You can try to let composer find a compatible version by not specifying a version:
`composer require drupal/console`